# Fix/replace worn-through side-button on Garmin Edge 520

Tags: replacement, bike-computer, garmin

My cycling computers "down" sidebutton has worn through due to my bad habit of only skipping through data pages using the lower of the two buttons. Rubber has perforated and it fell off during a ride, so I don't have anything to glue back in...

[image]

It still works but it is a near to a safety risk trying to press the inner mechanics during a ride. I'm aware that in most scenarios I could still scroll the other way or even re-arrange screens to accommodate for it, but is there a way to fix this, has anybody a good idea how or has even done a similar repair? It's also not ideal that the IP protection is voided and the next wet ride could end my beloved Edge after over 4 years of partnership. Yeah, I'm a keeper.

Garmin doesn't officially sell replacement parts, only cases (which wouldn't help to actuate the button internals), I've only seen one or two used parts on Ebay, but located in the US and I'm in the EU, so shipping costs would probably be higher than the part's price.

(I'm aware that this is only remotely cycling-related but perhaps somebody had the same issue since the buttons inherently wear on use on any kind of similar device).

### Update

After getting some useful responses on parts on the internet, I shied away from dirty glue jobs. The whole back of the device can be found (with and without battery) on various internet portals, mostly shipping from the East but a defect or used full Edge 520 unit might also be suitable, considering that a new 540 costs over 300€.

In my case, 25€ (which is less than 1/10 of a new 540), so it was worth the money because I'm still fine with battery life and features of the 2016 model and that probably keeps it alive for another two or three years, hopefully.

### Temporary fix

Here's what I came up with

- From inside the case, I covered the hole with tape
- The new *button* is the tailpiece of a zip-tie, glued onto the tape
- The ugly part: As protection and to give everything a more rubberish feel, I just covered the hole with Pattex glue which never full hardens out

[image]

It kind of works, probably not forever but at least temporary until the replacement case arrives from China, probably not until August.

Comment: I have the same issue with the power button on Edge Explore. It just works like this (about a year now). But sometimes is fiddly to press when wearing winter gloves.

Comment: @ArtGertner Yeah, "it works" is what I heard quite often from junior employees in my day job as software engineer^^ It is a bit of a pain because it takes way more focus and twice as long to actually hit the button. I don't race but it is still a pain. Thought about getting a frame-color-matching case and glue in a piece of plastic that hits the actuator, but any other kind of DIY fix is appreciated, too...

Comment: I see the difference in your case. Mine is a power button so I only need to press it before and after ride normally when I'm off the bike. Yours is used during the ride....

Comment: Where in the EU are you and how quick do you want a replacement?

Comment: @ArtGertner Yeah, the "back button" on the other side is also showing the same kind of wear, only a matter of time. I'm in Austria, its not the end of the world (I'd probably try getting used to using the other button) but it would be great if I had a solution in a month or so. If it dies on a rainy ride, I'd temporarily use my Forerunner or an even older Edge until I'd probaby just get a new 830...

Comment: It's against the rules to link products here. Especially counterfeit products... But I'll give you a hint. You can buy an edge 520 case with all buttons and a new battery from China for about €20. It won't be original or manufactured by garmin. But for what you need it will do just fine

Comment: @ArtGertner Thanks, I had a look at *that page* but (yet) couldn't find an offer that ships to Austria, but I'll keep trying. Let's see if I find one that has a reasonable price for an old Garmin and ships here.

Comment: The keyword here is "shell" not "case"    Do look out for confusion when searching listings like https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-garmin-edge-520-shell.html  sometimes the sellers are using a translator and words may not be right.  Photos are more reliable.

Comment: I’m unfamiliar with these devices, but if you only ever need one of the two up/down buttons, you could just fill the hole with silicone caulk/sealant or something. Actually, come to think of it, if you carefully apply the sealant, you might even be able to preserve the button’s functionality.

Comment: @MaplePanda Perhaps a hybrid of some rigid material, such a small piece of plastic covered in silicone could do. Thought of something like that. I'd just need to be extra careful because the circuit board is exposed and I don't know how well it handles heat if material drips into the case.

Comment: @Criggie Aliexpress didn't show any offers at all when searching in the app, via Google, I only got deeplinks that never shipped to my location. Anyway, I cleared a case for 25€ including shipping via Ebay, now I just need to keep the unit dry and alive and find out how to disassemble the case, probably needs a plastic opening tool or something like that...

Comment: Had the same kind of issue with a hiking GPS unit (also from Garmin). The rubbery compound seems to not withstand time very well, so what seem to be the best solution is a case replacement, but I couldn't find one. The issue being: if the compound is degraded, a localized fix is only good as a temporary fix to wait for a more durable solution, as it may appear later somewhere else.

Comment: Until it arrives, at least put some tape over the hole to keep the rain out.  High-strength electrical tape or waterproof clear repair tape would be better than duct tape here

Comment: 3rd party spares can be a very good solution.  I'd also look at what's available damaged ("spares & repairs") 2nd hand - on some designs a cracked screen could leave the part you want untouched, but on others you'd need the front of the shell to be intact.

Comment: @DoNuT *"Perhaps a hybrid of some rigid material, such a small piece of plastic covered in silicone could do. "* I'd glue a scrap of plastic onto the button using quick-setting epoxy (to get the height), then cover with silicone.  Not much silicone to start with, just enough to close the gap.  I wouldn't be too concerned with overheating.  Silicone has better thermal conductivity than air, and anyway the main heat load is external in the form of direct sunlight.  It must be given how much energy is stored in the battery and how long that takes to be released

Comment: I got a quick fix for the button, just some tape from the inside and then I glued a piece of suitable plastic on top of it which gives the button a bit more reach and haptic feedback. However, disassembing is pretty much pulling apart glued parts and the battery connector was a nightmare to get back in, let's hope it stays in place and the device doesn't die mid-ride because of it getting loose.

Comment: However, one of the buttons on the PCB lost it's metal framing that holds the internal "trigger" in place, had to apply the same fix on another button ... so, it is still somewhat functional but I'm not sure for how long ... lets see if the new case helps, that stuff is just not meant to be taken apart once it leaves the factory...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I wanted to follow up on this topic and how it went for me...**

After two weeks, I got a replacement case from overseas for reasonable money.

There is no spare part from Garmin since replacement isn't just swapping a case, you definitely have to disassemble your device, which includes peeling off the display glued to the case and removing cables/connectors between display, PCB and battery.

I can't post any links but there are two ways to get a replacement

- Just look out for an Edge sold as 'defect' on the market platform of your choice - it shouldn't matter if the screen is broken, battery's dead or the PCB failed as long as you can strip it apart and re-use the rear body/shell
- Various e-commerce platforms (located in China) offer replacement parts - searching for *Garmin Edge 520 shell* gives you good results. It is up to your judgement whether an offering is counterfeit, most of them look like refurbished original parts, so just somebody doing an extra step over buying a defect unit.

At least on my order, I got a clearly used shell (with dirt under the USB port cover) that was equally bad as mine. When test-pressing the buttons, all five of them immediately ruptured because of the old rubber, which is no surprise because the Edge *20 series was phased out years ago and while some may be used more gently, you can't cheat age in that regard when it comes to exposed rubber. It might be that it would have held up better if I installed it and it had pressed against the PCBs actuators but sure not for long.

[image: New case buttons failed immediately]

If you get a decent one that stood the test of time, I'd suggest to *look for one including battery* because otherwise, you will have to do some re-wiring against the new cases' speaker. You have to pull out cables and and push the new ones (1A) in the back of the connector to the PCB (1B). Admittedly, I'm not good at microelectronics and soldering but it seems like try and error and in best case, you get sound on the new device, or you just skip this step.

Also, pushing back the connector (1B) into the PCB (1C) is quite fiddly, I pretty much ruined it on my numerous attempts. It still worked when I finally put everything together but it didn't lock in, so you have to be extra careful that it doesn't disconnect already when you put the screen module back in, or on a bump on the street. Use a strip of duct tape or glue to be on the safe side.

[image]

Also, the small metal frames holding the buttons/actuators on the PCB in place are very fragile, one just fell off including the button just when I took the 520 apart for the first time. Then, the button doesn't stay in place and you have to be creative, again.

I finally went with buying a new Edge 540 because all of the above is a good sign that you had your device for way too long and it won't get back to how was in a pristine state after attempting such repairs.

Sorry that this is more of a rant than useful instructions but that's my main learning: these devices are not meant to be refurbished, at least by amateurs like me.

Comment: I have similar issue, mine was the enter button, on top right. Yeah i bought the new 840 but i still would like to fix it. I guess it’s gonna be tough. Thanks for the details and photos.

Comment: @Ken It is definitely doable if you take your time and don't rush things. Most of it is doable without special tools, even though it might be fiddly, like the speaker cables - with special tools, it would have been easier to expose the wire and press it back into the connector. Also, you need to glue the screen back on, it'll stick on the original case after cutting it but my replacement had it totally stripped, that probably depend on where you get it from - I think, there are no spares, just parts from defective head units being sold.

Comment: It is a pity that it fails.just because of rubber buttons. My very old handheld Garmin etrex GPS still works well, although affected by the week counter overflow, just the rubber around the device has been very slightly loose for a long time, but the buttons in it work well. I used to use it extensively in the 2000s and early 2010s. My Edge Explore 2 does not seem to have rubber buttons.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Classic constructive weak point. My 520 would have done another 4-5 years, all working fine and battery life still excellent. But Garmin know their mistake, the 540 doesn't have these rubberized buttons but some hard-shell plastic ones - for a reason, I suppose...^^

Answer (score 3):

[image: Fix for Power Button Cover Fail on Garmin 520]

Here's a potential fix for the power button cover on the garmin 520 failing.  I took some 0.125" dia. brake cable sheathing (Tubing that is used to cover exposed cable on a bike so it doesn't scratch the paint.) and after several tries I was able to cut a piece of the tubing that fit snugly in the opening for the power button.  Then I added electrical tape wrapped twice around the center of the piece to make the diameter wider so the little button gets pushed.  I have only used it on one ride - need to do some further field testing but so far so good.  I also need to put some silicon around the edges so it is waterproof.

Comment: Nice hack!  You're right this needs some silicon RTV or Sugru to have a chance of surviving the rain.   Or stick a plastic bag over the whole head unit and tape it shut.

Comment: That's smart and something fitting you can easily recycle. Silicone should sort the job but I didn't have any around so I went for a the ugly Pattex (tm) hack. Definitely needs something that stays flexible, so no superglue etc. Good luck, my 520 didn't really survive the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

I did a similar fix for the failed rubber cover on the power button of my aging Garmin Edge 510.  I clipped a short (about 3/8 in.) piece of coated wire (actually, a phone line with three thin lines inside the outer cover), dropped it in the hole over the switch and taped it down with electrical tape.  Seems to work fine, and should be pretty weather safe.  Tim

Comment: Nice and easy. I think most solutions other than trying to replace the back of the computer will turn out to be some kind of rigid object put into the hole and fixated using tape/glue. I could imagine it is waterproof enough as long as the tape sticks but I assume with repeated usage/flex, dirt ingress and being exposed to the elements, it'll require renewal from time to time. The worst that could happen is that the "button" falls off and you need a new one. If I had it around when trying my temporary fix above, I would have tried hot glue (with care) or sanitary silicone.