Is the Garmin Edge 530 still a good choice for a beginner in 2024?
I'm new to cycling and looking for a reliable bike computer that suits my needs as a beginner. My rides are primarily for commuting and weekend excursions, typically 30-40 km, on roads and occasionally gravel. I've come across the Garmin Edge 530 for around $290, but since it's a 2019 model, I'm wondering if it's still worth the investment in 2024.
Here are the key features I'm looking for:

Accurate ride tracking
Reliable navigation for urban commutes and countryside rides, with support for route imports from Strava, Komoot, etc.
Strong GNSS (preferably multi-band) and reliable sensor connectivity (speed, cadence, heart rate monitor, etc.)
Ability to track rides as workouts and sync data with health apps like Samsung Health and Google Fit
A device that will remain useful as I gain more experience, so I won't need to upgrade soon

I'm also considering the Wahoo Elemnt Bolt V2, priced at $275. However, I've noticed that the Wahoo app has a low rating (2.9/5) on the Play Store, and I'm concerned about potential issues with data reliability.
Given these criteria, would the Garmin Edge 530 still be a solid choice, or should I consider the Wahoo or another option?
Additional context: I previously used a Sigma Rox 4.0, but I had issues with it deleting rides and unreliable connections, so I returned it.

What are your needs, as a beginner rider?    Personally my needs were "speed and clock" so a $20 wired cateye was sufficient.  Though I tend to sit on "elapsed time" rather than clock nowdays.

@Criggie my needs are navigation. Some insight into my cycling habits and performance over time, helping me grow and get better in it.

From what I've seen, Garmin is (currently) better with performance tracking features, Wahoo with navigation (Wahoo is much faster at recomputing routes when you deviate from the original track).
There are also different design philosophies, Garmin considers that the device should be self-sufficient, while Wahoo considers that only the basic things need to be done on the device, and everything that is too complex to be done with 6 buttons should be done on the phone (for example, you can navigate to points of interests from the device, but if you want to enter a new destination you'll need to do it through the phone, but routing is computed on device and faster than on Garmin devices). I wouldn't be put off by the low rating on Google Play Store, both are solid platforms with good support from their manufacturers. Garmin also often have the geekiest features — for example, you can install an app on the Garmin to control the lights depending on the ambient light, with Wahoo you can only choose between the built-in modes for the lights, and it only arrived this year through a software update.
The question is really to define your needs, you've already given some indications, so here are some comments:

navigation on urban commutes and for sport rides are two different needs, finding a single device/app that does both well is very hard. I prefer to use Google/Apple Maps for urban related navigation (easier input, more up to date, traffic information, no need for an additional device). My utility bikes have a smartphone mount, my sport bikes a Wahoo mount. Urban commutes are also much shorter, so less battery life issue, and you can turn off the screen for the parts that you know.
routes imports from Strava, Komoot and others is a basic feature for Garmin/Wahoo, that is done directly on the device (using Wifi), as well as syncing.
if you are not in a hurry, a smartphone and a smart watch can do the job (I don't know about Samsung, but with Apple, you can connect Bluetooth sensors to the watch, and then connect the Strava app if you want more complete metrics). The 530 is indeed 4 years old, so the support will be shorter than the 540 that has been recently released. So if you want the longest support, better to take the latest device. You can also wait for discounts on the latest devices, discounts are common for Garmin devices. In the case of Wahoo, hard to say when the v3 will be released though (the v2 is from 2021).


FWIW, in my experience Garmin units tend to be fragile and short-lived.  I've had a 500, 700, 1000, and just yesterday a 1030 die on me over the past decade or so.  Mostly because of the unit's storage going bad.  Yesterday's 1030 death was the touch screen becoming completely non-responsive to touch after it got some rain and sweat on it and then went completely wonky.  So I wouldn't be worried about how long a Garmin is going to be supported, I'd be more worried about it simply lasting.

@AndrewHenle On my side, I was using Garmin devices when I was in a hiking period. My fenix 3 (2015) still works very well, I also have a GPSMap 64 (2013), that is technically working, but the rubberized part of the casing has started disaggregating 2 years ago with makes it useless (no waterproofing) — like https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/89699/fix-replace-worn-through-side-button-on-garmin-edge-520 .

I still have a working eTrex Venture CX, just the rubber around is bad and the cycle counter has long overflown.

@AndrewHenle: Interesting, I had never heard of any Garmin unit failing. Me and my sisters have been using the Edges and Forerunners for years (the old sister professionally). In general the hardware has always seemed pretty solid to me, it’s the software side they can’t seem to get right.

More anecdotal evidence re Garmin being fragile here. I used an 810 for 9 years in all weather and I only replaced it when the rubber casing perished and water eventually got in through the hole in the side. My FR235 watch worked as my main watch for 8 years before a button stopped working after a week swimming in the sea (possibly coincidentally). Whether not being completely indestructible is a blocker is up to you but it certainly didn't stop me replacing them with an 840 and 255 respectively.

All of my Garmin devices still work fine, my oldest cycle computer is an 800 and I also have a much older hiking GPS (I think it's an etrax or similar) and a new watch which all work well. I've always found Garmin hardware to be pretty solid, the software can be a bit flakey at first but they do provide updated for quite a long time so issues usually get ironed out and new features added.

Bit of a frame challenge, but have you considered using your Smartphone? If you have a smartphone (preferably waterproof) with a bright screen and can get a good mount for it it would work nicely.
I have a Garmin Edge 840 and it’s really quite an expensive niche product. Navigation will always be mediocre on such a small screen. The on-device route calculation is also horrible. On a recent trip I actually ended up calculating a new route on the smartphone(much better with Osmand and Brouter) and transferring it to the Edge. In my opinion the biggest advantage of the Edge is the transflective display (readable even in direct sunlight) and the good battery runtime (it now actually manages ~20h, the old 820 ran dry after 5h). If you want electronic gimmicks I would recommend a power meter before an expensive GNSS bike computer.
The nice thing about a GNSS bike computer is really convenience. You have a dedicated device, turn it on, press start and ride without any distraction … as long as the firmware doesn’t crash. I actually don’t bring my smartphone on <100km rides.
Edit: One thing I also realized today morning: I rarely use the touchscreen of my Edge 840 during rides (it has the same physical buttons as the 540/530 in addition to the touchscreen) but for navigation I certainly like the touchscreen. With the physical buttons it’s very cumbersome to zoom and move around the map. In general the UI is somewhat difficult to use with the physical buttons. Other bike computers like the Karoo Hammerhead do it much better (for example the Hammerhead displays UI elements like “Save” and “Discard” right next to the corresponding physical button so you always know which one to press).

Thank you for your insight. A smartphone could be a nice option but then I will overuse the phone which will in turn reduce the battery life and the sun reflection as you mentioned. Also the battery life would be much less than these computers with the screen on. Why do you think a power meter is an essential piece?

“Also the battery life would be much less than these computers with the screen on.” In airplane mode I’ve found it to be quite okay. Definitely comparable to what my old Edge 820 achieved (but the 530/830 is a big upgrade in that regard) and sufficient for 5h rides. “Why do you think a power meter is an essential piece?” It makes pacing and training at certain intensities so much easier. With a power meter you no longer care about distance, speed, headwinds or luggage weight but only about duration and (average) power output.

Actually the biggest issue with smartphone as a bike computer is finding the right app. Osmand is great for navigation (and can now even display power meter data) but doesn’t offer lap times and the like. Dedicated cycling apps like Jepster or BikeComputer are better at displaying data but worse at (or incapable of) navigation.

Aren’t there durability concerns regarding using a phone mounted on your bars long term? IIRC the vibration can damage the camera autofocus over time.

@MaplePanda I remember having read something similar for motorbikes, not bikes. Quadlock sells for example a vibration dampener, has a positive list of motorbikes that requires it, and recommend to use it for other motorbikes. But I would also be concerned about that, to be honest.

@AlirezaM.Kamelabad I use a BlackView BV4900 running IPbike.  I can navigate a 300km day ride on a charge, by using aeroplane mode while moving and optimising my screen brightness.  Navigation is following a line, not turn-by-turn, which is as I like it - if you like turn-by-turn, try the RideWithGPS app.  I use just GPS, no (power/speed/cadence) sensors, which helps with the battery life - no bluetooth needed.  This is mainly road and gravel but also MTB, some quite rough stuff.  Just make sure the phone doesn't get ejected onto the road (clip a lanyard onto it)

@MaplePanda I've never had issues with that, but hitting the road a few times eventually breaks even ruggedised phones, which are often at the limit of thickness for clamp mounts.  Some form of secondary attachment is a good idea. Waterpoof phones don't play nicely with Quadlock - too big for the cases and the stick-on fixture makes them very fat as well as trying to stick to something deeply textured

If you want workout-style training a heart rate monitor is far cheaper than a power meter, and plenty for most riders.  I'm idly considering a power meter and some more structured training to go with it - for long days, not racing, I haven't felt the need so far

@MaplePanda different approach for phone fixing: I use a small top tube bag which has a transparent pocket in the top lid where I can put in the phone. Advantage: since the bag is soft, it dampens most of the vibrations. Slight disadvantage: since the bag sits behind the stem you have to look a bit back (almost between your knees) to see the display. Ok for navigation most of the time, a bit clunky if you want to use the phone to show ride metrics (speed, distance, time etc)

@AlirezaM.Kamelabad if you have an app with turn by turn navigation you can even put in one ear plug and turn off the phone display completely. I use this quite often and only have to stop and turn in the phone when I have the feeling that I did miss turn or at some unclear situations (think of two ways entering your road from the same side just some meters apart and you cannot tell from the audio which one was meant). Then you can easily use a classic bike computer for the ride specific data (speed, distance, etc)

@BenediktBauer: In my experience a big disadvantage of any transparent bag is that it makes the screen much harder to read and much harder to use. Turn instructions never worked for me, especially not for cycling where intersections are often unclear.

Also don't forget Garmin's ransomware episode.  That showed that they had no backups and no separation between subscriber data and their user LAN.   Security was clearly not even vaguely in their design, and that's likely to persisit.   I wouldn't go Garmin.

@Michael Well, the part about display readability is true. Today in the morning I noticed that this isn't an issue for me since I do almost all of my riding in the dark or dawn. I have quite good experiences with turn instructions, but I never had to navigate urban areas or even worse urban areas with bad GPS reception where you don't get a good localisation radius.

(partly @BenediktBauer) a cheap (~½ the price of a basic Garmin) waterproof phone is better than a nicer phone in a waterproof case because of reflections requiring greater screen brightness and wasting battery.

...Spoken turn-by-turn is problematic - a speaker has to be really loud over traffic, but two earphones affect the ability to hear traffic (and/or still have to be loud).  I find one earpiece even worse: my hearing is decent but my directional hearing is very good and that's ruined by having one ear stopped up.  Plus earphones fall out, and I'd rather not have my ears tied to the bike (no turn-by-turn is good enough to use in a pocket).  Better is a beep and a screen that lights up.  But if you do go with voice navigation, use anything other than Google

FWIW, Quadlock is known to be a very secure mount. There are competitors. I don't follow the space, but others might do some research. A lot of serious cyclists have moved on from smartphones, but I agree it should definitely be considered as an option - when you know your needs better and/or you advance as a rider, then you upgrade.

Quad Lock also makes a vibration dampener now (mostly intended for motorbikes) if you are concerned about your phone’s camera.

@WeiwenNg if only Quadlock did an holder for already-waterproof/rugged phones that didn't rely on gluing a big lump on the back.  Typically you can't get cases for these phones (for my current one you can, but the weak point in the chain is then a flimsy bit of plastic from AliExpress that interferes with the lanyard fitting)

... I'm seeing people moving back to phones in the long-distance community, partly after using their phone as a backup and finding they prefer it to their primary device.  A lot of this is the far superior map rendering, giving the ability to reroute manually on the fly.

@Michael not sure that the quad lock motorbike vibration dampener can be used on bike mounts.

@ChrisH Just out of curiosity, what is the prevalence of dynamo hubs in the long distance community? (Question in relation with the use of phones as primary devices)

@Rеnаud: Hasn’t the prevalence of dynamo hubs decreased a lot with power banks and fast charging? With a 10000mAh power bank you can navigate with a phone with screen on for probably more than 20 hours and recharge power bank and phone in like an hour total?

@Michael I’m under the impression that a modern dynamo could still beat batteries for lights (especially in colder temperatures), and there are chargers that can be installed at the steerer tube cap, so probably lighter than a power-bank. But thinking about it, a dynamo could probably charge a Garmin or a Wahoo, but not a phone.

@ Rеnаud high but not 100%. 50% for me personally but that's also my estimate on a 24h 400km event. So dynamos are more common than navigating by phone.  Also @Michael my setup is a cheap one and only gives 500mA. Even so that means essentially unlimited phone power for summer touring (some but not much use of lights). My phone does go up even with the screen bright enough for full sunlight, but slowly.

As someone who bought the 530 in 2024:

Accurate ride tracking

Yes! No Problems with that

Reliable navigation for urban commutes and countryside rides, with
support for route imports from Strava, Komoot, etc.

I don't import routes from Strava but exporting to Strava is automatic.
Komoot integration is super easy. It automatically syncs your routes from Komoot.

Strong GNSS (preferably multi-band) and reliable sensor connectivity
(speed, cadence, heart rate monitor, etc.)

No problems here.

Ability to track rides as workouts and sync data with health apps
like Samsung Health and Google Fit

I don't use these Apps, but automatic sync works flawless with Komoot, Strava and Garmin Connect.

A device that will remain useful as I gain more experience, so I
won't need to upgrade soon

The only thing that could be better in my opinion is routing, when deviating from your planned route.

Generally speaking, it is relatively safe to buy slightly older Garmin devices - Garmin has a good track record of keeping them upgraded with bug fixes and often even new features for many years.
Comparing the 530 vs 540 (the current, as of 08/2024, flagship in the 5xx series), you do see some improvements (e.g. USB-C; double amount of storage; etc.), but actually "defining" new features - not so much. If you absolutely do require the new ClimbPro (without route), then yes, you must get the 540. But aside from that, it seems that someone who has a 530 already has little reason to upgrade to 540. The one real kicker is dual-band GPS; depending on where you ride this might be a real deal-breaker for the 530, or totally irrelevant.
For comparison, I recently watched some Olympian cyclist, and they used the 540. If that device is good enough for them, then it (or the 530) is good enough for you and me.
So taking these two arguments together - the 530 being "good enough", and Garmin usually not dropping devices from support very soon - getting a 530 and enjoying the lesser price point should be just fine. The 530 still has dozens and dozens of features which you may or may not use as an amateur (certainly true for me), and especially if you already are in the Garmin ecosystem with, say, one of their watches, it is almost a no-brainer.
Regarding whether to take a Garmin vs a different brand,
here is a review between the 540 and two competitors https://www.dcrainmaker.com/2024/05/bike-bike-gps-2024-garmin-hammerhead-karoo-review.html, from mid 2024. Everything said about the 540 applies to the 530 as well, except for the explicit differences, which you can see here for example: https://www.cyclistshub.com/garmin-edge-530-vs-edge-540/ . You have to make up your own mind whether the new features are worth the price to you.

For a pro cyclist the small size and weight of the Edge 540 (or 840) is probably a big selling point. As long as it can display power data reliably and with good readability they probably don’t need much more.
